# How do I hide and show buttons with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been creating a pokemon matching game but I don't know how to hide the cauculate button if anyone knows the answer please tell me. I've tried some websites but it didn't work. Could you guys help me?? I've tried forget_pack() and others. Also if there are any bugs tell me. I am using Visual Studio Code to write my code.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pygame
import time
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import random
from pygame import mixer

from tkinter import *

try:
    # Tkinter for Python 2.xx
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    # Tkinter for Python 3.xx
    import tkinter as tk
APP_TITLE = "Pokemon Game"
APP_XPOS = 100
APP_YPOS = 100
APP_WIDTH = 300
APP_HEIGHT = 200
IMAGE_PATH = "images/"
mixer.init()

class CreateCanvasObject(object):
    def __init__(self, canvas, image_name, xpos, ypos):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.image_name = image_name
        self.xpos, self.ypos = xpos, ypos

        #image = Image.open("C:\\Users\\happy\\Desktop\\test.jpg")
        #photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

        self.tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(
            file="{}{}".format(IMAGE_PATH, image_name))
        self.image_obj= canvas.create_image(
            xpos, ypos, image=self.tk_image)



#        self.tk_image = tk.PhotoImage(
#            file="{}{}".format(IMAGE_PATH, image_name))
#        self.image_obj= canvas.create_image(
#            xpos, ypos, image=self.tk_image)
        canvas.tag_bind(self.image_obj, '<Button1-Motion>', self.move)
        canvas.tag_bind(self.image_obj, '<ButtonRelease-1>', self.release)
        self.move_flag = False
        #self.text_id = self.canvas.create_text(950,50, font='Times 24',text="                                                                 ")
    def move(self, event):
        #self.image_obj[0]:
        #print(self.image_1.x)
        if self.move_flag:
            new_xpos, new_ypos = event.x, event.y
            self.canvas.move(self.image_obj,
                new_xpos-self.mouse_xpos ,new_ypos-self.mouse_ypos)
            self.mouse_xpos = new_xpos
            self.mouse_ypos = new_ypos
        else:
            self.move_flag = True
            self.canvas.tag_raise(self.image_obj)
            self.mouse_xpos = event.x
            self.mouse_ypos = event.y
    def release(self, event):
        self.move_flag = False
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        #print(self)
        self.master = master
        self.master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=400, bg='#AFFAAF',
            highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        pokemons = ["Charizard", "Charmeleon", 'Charmander', 'Blastoise', 'Wartortle','Squirtle','Venusaur','Ivysaur','Bulbsaur']
        random.shuffle(pokemons)
        for i in range(0,9):
            self.image_1 = CreateCanvasObject(self.canvas,pokemons[i]+'.png', 100*i+350, 500)
            #self.image_2 =CreateCanvasObject(self.canvas, "Charmeleon.png", 200, 500)
            #self.image_3 = CreateCanvasObject(self.canvas, "Charmander.png", 300, 500)
            #self.image_4 =CreateCanvasObject(self.canvas, "Blastoise.png", 400, 500)
            #self.image_5 = CreateCanvasObject(self.canvas, "Wartortle.png", 500, 500)
            #self.image_6 =CreateCanvasObject(self.canvas, "Squirtle.png", 600, 500)
            #self.image_7 =CreateCanvasObject(self.canvas, "Venusaur.png", 700, 500)
            #self.image_8 = CreateCanvasObject(self.canvas, "Ivysaur.png", 800, 500)
            #self.image_9 =CreateCanvasObject(self.canvas, "Bulbsaur.png", 900, 500)
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(350, 50, 600, 300) # fill='white')
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(650, 50, 900, 300) #, fill='white')
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(950, 50, 1200, 300) #, fill='white')
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(320, 550, 1250, 450)
        self.text_id1 = self.canvas.create_text(500,750, font='Times 24',text="")
        self.text_id = self.canvas.create_text(650,750, font='Times 24',text="")
        self.text_id2 = self.canvas.create_text(800,750, font='Times 24',text="")
        self.text_id3 = self.canvas.create_text(1000,750, font='Times 24',text="")
        self.text_id4 = self.canvas.create_text(800,400, font='Times 24',text="Drag the pokemons in their right evolution place. When you finished, press [Calculate] ")
        set1={pokemons.index('Charizard')+1,pokemons.index('Charmeleon')+1,pokemons.index('Charmander')+1}
        set2={pokemons.index('Blastoise')+1,pokemons.index('Wartortle')+1,pokemons.index('Squirtle')+1}
        set3={pokemons.index('Venusaur')+1,pokemons.index('Ivysaur')+1,pokemons.index('Bulbsaur')+1}
        labelframe=LabelFrame(self.canvas,text="",width=1500,height=800,highlightcolor="yellow",highlightbackground="red",highlightthickness=10)  
        labelframe.grid(padx = 0, pady = 0)
        def destroy():
            labelframe.destroy()
        self.mybutton2 = tk.Button(labelframe, text='Play', width=50, height=5, command=destroy)
        self.mybutton2.place(x=0,y=0)
    


        pokemon_names = []
        mixer.music.load('Muisc (1).wav')
        mixer.music.play(-1)


        def button_event():
            Frame1=[]
            Frame2=[]
            Frame3=[]
            for i in range(1,10): #print out every image object's coordinates
                #print(i, self.canvas.coords(i))
                if self.canvas.coords(i)[0] >= 350 and self.canvas.coords(i)[0] <= 600 and self.canvas.coords(i)[1] >= 50 and self.canvas.coords(i)[1] <= 300:
                    Frame1.append(i)
                if self.canvas.coords(i)[0] >= 650 and self.canvas.coords(i)[0] <= 900 and self.canvas.coords(i)[1] >= 50 and self.canvas.coords(i)[1] <= 300:
                    Frame2.append(i)
                if self.canvas.coords(i)[0] >= 950 and self.canvas.coords(i)[0] <= 1200 and self.canvas.coords(i)[1] >= 50 and self.canvas.coords(i)[1] <= 300:
                    Frame3.append(i)
            TP=0
            FP=0
            Level = 1



          
            

            for i in Frame1:
                for j in Frame1:
                    if i<j:
                        if (i in set1 and j in set1) or (i in set2 and j in set2) or (i in set3 and j in set3):
                            TP+=1
                        else:
                            FP+=1

            Undiscovered=0
            for i in set1:
                for j in set1:
                    if i<j:
                        Undiscovered+=1
                        if (i in Frame1 and j in Frame1) or (i in Frame2 and j in Frame2) or (i in Frame3 and j in Frame3):
                            Undiscovered-=1

            for i in Frame2:
                for j in Frame2:
                    if i<j:
                        if (i in set1 and j in set1) or (i in set2 and j in set2) or (i in set3 and j in set3):
                            TP+=1
                        else:
                            FP+=1

            #Undiscovered=0
            for i in set2:
                for j in set2:
                    if i<j:
                        Undiscovered+=1
                        if (i in Frame1 and j in Frame1) or (i in Frame2 and j in Frame2) or (i in Frame3 and j in Frame3):
                            Undiscovered-=1




            

            for i in Frame3:
                for j in Frame3:
                    if i<j:
                        if (i in set1 and j in set1) or (i in set2 and j in set2) or (i in set3 and j in set3):
                            TP+=1
                        else:
                            FP+=1

            #Undiscovered=0
            for i in set3:
                for j in set3:
                    if i<j:
                        Undiscovered+=1
                        if (i in Frame1 and j in Frame1) or (i in Frame2 and j in Frame2) or (i in Frame3 and j in Frame3):
                            Undiscovered-=1

            self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.text_id,text="Score: "+str(TP*2-FP-Undiscovered))
            #self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.text_id2,text="Incorrect: "+str(FP))
            #self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.text_id3,text="Undiscovered: "+str(Undiscovered))
            #self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.text_id1,text="Level: "+str(Level))
            #print("TP=", TP, "FP=", FP, "Undiscovered=", Undiscovered)



                    #if self.canvas.coords(i)[0] >= 400 and self.canvas.coords(i)[0] <= 650 and self.canvas.coords(i)[1] >= 400 and self.canvas.coords(i)[1] <= 650:
                        #print(yes)


                      #print(self.image_1.x, self.image_1)
                
            #print(self.image_2.xpos, self.image_2.ypos)
            #print(self.image_3.xpos, self.image_3.ypos)
            #print(self.image_4.xpos, self.image_4.ypos)
            #print(self.image_5.xpos, self.image_5.ypos)
            #print(self.image_6.xpos, self.image_6.ypos)
        self.mybutton = tk.Button(self, text='Calculate your score', width=50, height=5, command=button_event)
        self.mybutton.place(x=600,y=600)
    def close(self):
        print("Application-Shutdown")
        self.master.destroy()
def main():
    app_win = tk.Tk()
    app_win.title(APP_TITLE)
    app_win.geometry("+{}+{}".format(APP_XPOS, APP_YPOS))

    #app_win.geometry("{}x{}".format(APP_WIDTH, APP_HEIGHT))
    #def button_event():
    #    print(app_win.)
#    mybutton = tk.Button(app_win, text='Calculate', command=button_event)#   mybutton.pack()
    app = Application(app_win).pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    app_win.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Since you use `.place(...)` on the button, you need to use `.place_forget()` to remove it.

Comment: so um do you know how to show the button

Comment: You already did it, use `.place(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you - [Hiding Tkinter Widgets](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-hide-recover-and-delete-tkinter-widgets/#:%7E:text=We%20could%20hide%20the%20Tkinter,()%20method%20in%20this%20section.)

Use .place_forget()